# Prawn/PDF: Multiple formats/text on one line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, prawn, prawnto

When I try the following code:

```
text "Hello "
text "World"
```

They render Hello on top of World instead of World right after Hello. I have some complicated formatting (highlighting, different font sizes etc) on text that I need on one line. I know that the `:inline_formatting` option exists but it seems this is too complicated to use that option.

I have the following code:

**highlight_callback.rb:**

```
class HighlightCallback
  def initialize(options)
    @color = options[:color]
    @document = options[:document]
  end

  def render_behind(fragment)
    original_color = @document.fill_color
    @document.fill_color = @color
    @document.fill_rectangle(fragment.top_left,
    fragment.width,
    fragment.height)

    @document.fill_color = original_color
  end
end
```

**order.pdf.prawn:**

```
highlight = HighlightCallback.new(:color => 'ffff00', :document => self)

#code....

text "Authorized Signature: "
formatted_text [{:text => "_" * 15, :callback => highlight }], :size => 20
```

which is producing the attached image. How can I get the signature line on the same level as the text?

[image]

Comment: hmm, never did it like that. I guess you have to move the pointer yourself. But prawn can easily calculate the width of your text

Comment: how do I move the pointer? I feel like I should be able to give it a set of coords after the first text to reset the cursor and then continue on that same spot after my text.

Comment: you might need to use `text_box` with `:at` option http://prawnpdf.org/docs/0.11.1/Prawn/Text.html#method-i-text

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that. If that seems to work, I'll let you know. Make a full answer for the ? and I'll upvote and mark it as correct.

Comment: That did the trick! Post a detailed answer and I'll mark it as correct and upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To place text at a exact position you can use `text_box` with the option `:at`.

You can get the width of your text with `pdf.width_of(str)` (use the same style optione `:size` etc. otherwise it will use the default settings to calculate)

Answer (score 8):

## Ruby 2.5.1

### Rails 5.2.0

It's enough to change method `text` to `text_box`, i.e.:

```
bounding_box([0, cursor], width: 540, height: 40) do
  stroke_color 'FFFF00'
  stroke_bounds

  date = 'Date: '
  text_box date, style: :bold

  text_box DateTime.now.strftime('%Y/%m/%d'), at: [bounds.left + width_of(date), cursor]
  text_box "Signature ________________", align: :right
end
```

#### Example: [image: Rendered PDF Page]